# Opening a browser to select a file from CMD

Tags: windows, user-interface, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently working on a little side project installer with batch files.

My batch file first checks if JAVA_HOME is defined in environment variables. If it isn't, I would like to be able to open a explorer so the user can select that path to his JAVA folder. 
The other option I would like to ask about is if anyone knows of a nice GUI interface (non java and open source) so I prompt the user to select his JAVA folder and set JAVA_HOME
(I know I could prompt the user to enter the path thru the command prompt)

heres an example

```
IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
echo JAVA_HOME was not set, please enter path to JAVA folder: 
set /p JAVA_HOME= ---> PROMPT GUI FOR SELECTION
```

Thank you any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a Usenet post I had squirreled away.

From: "Matt Williamson" 
Newsgroups: alt.msdos.batch.nt
Subject: Re: Email via VBScript
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2007 09:58:19 -0400

```
@echo off
:BrowseFolder
set Result=
set input=%1

:: Temporary files
set vbs=%temp%\_.vbs
set tmp=%temp%\_.cmd

:: Build VBScript file
findstr "'%skip%VBS" "%~f0" > "%vbs%"

:: Run the script with WSH
cscript //nologo "%vbs%" > "%tmp%"

:: Read the output file and set Path as Env variable %Result%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%tmp%) do %%a

echo %result% & pause
DEL %VBS%
DEL %TMP%

endlocal & goto :EOF

'
'.......................................................
'The Visual Basic Script
'
set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'VBS
set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 'VBS
sInput=WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%input%") 'VBS
set folder=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,replace(sInput,chr(34),""),0) 'VBS
if typename(folder)="Nothing" Then  'VBS
wscript.echo "set Result=Dialog Cancelled" 'VBS
WScript.Quit(1) 'VBS
end if 'VBS
set folderItems=folder.Items() 'VBS
set folderItem=folderItems.Item() 'VBS
pathname=folderItem.Path 'VBS
wscript.echo "set Result="& chr(34) & pathname & chr(34) 'VBS
```